# Suppressing a iframe popup and copying its link?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, popup

I have a page that has an iframe embedded in it. If I click on some link in the iframe (such as a google search or image) it launches a separate instance of my web browser, that directs it to that location. My goal is to suppress the pop-up of the new browser and just copy the URL that the link has. After, the user can just paste the link somewhere. A similar example is on the website [Memeful](http://memeful.com/). The user can just click on an gif and the link gets copied.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 clipboard API for this. Note only work for modern browser [Clipboard browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard)

```js
function copyText () {
  var tmpElem = document.createElement('div'),
    selection;
  tmpElem.textContent = 'Your text want to copy';
  document.body.appendChild(tmpElem);
  if (document.selection) {
    selection = document.body.createTextRange();
    selection.moveToElementText(tmpElem);
    selection.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = document.createRange();
    selection.selectNode(tmpElem);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(selection);
  }
  document.execCommand('copy');
  tmpElem.remove();
}
```

```html
<button onclick='copyText()'>Copy on clipboard</button>
```